# HTML Submit-button: Different value / button-text?

Tags: html, forms

I'd like to create an HTML form submit button with the *value* `'add tag'`, however, the web page is in Swedish, so I'd like to have a different *button text*.

That is, I want to have a button like

[image]

but I want to have my code like

```
if (request.getParameter(cmd).equals("add tag"))
    tags.addTag( /*...*/ );
```

**Is this possible? If so, how?**

Comment: I think the value should not matter. You should simply check for the presence of "add_tag" in your POST data

Comment: I read this as "I want the text of the input not to be relevant to my server side processing" so that when you have several translations for a form you don't get one of several text values posted.  It matters when your form has several submit buttons and you want to do if(request.getParameter("submit-type").equals("add-tag") ... to see which one was pressed.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

It's possible using the `button` element.

```
<button name="name" value="value" type="submit">Sök</button>
```

From the [W3C page on `button`:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content.

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't work as advertised on IE6/7.  This article may correct the problem, but you'll have problems if you're using asp.net or another framework that disallows HTML on postback:

http://allinthehead.com/retro/330/coping-with-internet-explorers-mishandling-of-buttons

Comment: you could also just use the name property which provides output in POST

Answer (score 25):

Following the @greg0ire suggestion in comments:

```
<input type="submit" name="add_tag" value="Lägg till tag" />
```

In your server side, you'll do something like:

```
if (request.getParameter("add_tag") != null)
    tags.addTag( /*...*/ );
```

(Since I don't know that language (java?), there may be syntax errors.)

I would prefer the `<button>` solution, but [it doesn't work as expected on IE < 9](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp).

Answer (score 16):

There are plenty of answers here explaining what you could do (I use the different field name one) but the simple (and as-yet unstated) answer to your question is 'no' - you can't have a different text and value using just HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got you right, but, as I understand, you could use an additional hidden field with the value "add tag" and let the button have the desired text.

Comment: Not helpful with multiple buttons on the same form, which I think is the OP's problem.

Comment: Cannot see any evidence from his question that there are multiple buttons on the same form.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle "adding tag" via JScript:

```
<form ...>
<button onclick="...">any text you want</button>
</form>
```

Or above if handle via page reload

Comment: Yay, JS required for every single form, regardless of simplicity.  Welcome to ASP.NET.

Comment: As an ASP.Net developer, I can confirm this. :P Assuming you're still living in the days of webforms anyway. ASP.Net MVC is a lot better. No viewstates, globally wrapping forms, etc.