# input type button - label vs value

Tags: html

I think that the normal behavior of a button like the one below is that the `value` attribute serves as a label as well:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="DeleteAnswer22" />
```

Is it possible to have separate attributes for display label and value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Submit-button: Different value / button-text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use the [HTML Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element, with type `submit`, instead:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="DeleteAnswer22">Delete Answer 22</button>
```

This will result in a submit button that sends the value `DeleteAnswer22` but displays "Delete Answer 22".

Comment: This solution may have problems with some browsers. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134631/button-text-different-than-value-submitted-in-query-string

Comment: @MuratTutumlu do you know if these problems are still relevant? The information that post refers to no longer exists.