# Button text different than value submitted in query string

Tags: html

**Short version:**

How can I have my form's button label text differ from the value submitted to the server *without* using the `<button>` tag?

**Long version:**

I wanted to have the text that appeared in a button in a form to be different than the value submitted in the query string.  So, I looked around, and came across this approach...

```
<button name="method" type="submit" value="repackage">Update Config</button>
```

...and that worked on IE9 on one of my laptops and I was happy.  The user saw "Update Config" and the server received `method=repackage` in the query string.

Then I brought this app to work and ran it on a workstation, also with IE9.  But something had gone wrong.  The user still saw "Update Config", but the server now received `method=Update%20Config` in the query string.

So I investigated some more.  I found that www.w3schools.com recommmended not using a `<button>` tag in a form.  They say: "If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form" in [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp).  This seems to be what I am experiencing.

So I looked some more, and found lots of conflicting information about the right way to do this.  For example [here is a Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701831/input-type-button-label-vs-value) that asks exactly this question, but the accepted answer is to use the `<button>` tag.  I can say from experience and research that this is not a reliable approach.

Comment: @Daedalus:  Thank you for that link.  Do you think perhaps w3schools.com is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no other way try this:

Use an **image button**, instead of button. An image button will work as ordinary submit button, but you create an image of the desired button text (no one can change your text then).

```
 <input type="image" src="http://images.webestools.com/buttons.php?frm=2&btn_type=31&txt=Update+Config" name="method" value="repackage">
```

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to think that would be necessary.  But it feels just a little work-intensive, especially if I will do this often.

Answer (score 2):

For newcomers: With some CSS this works like a charm as of September 2017:

```html
<form>
    <label style="padding:5px; cursor:pointer; border:solid 1px; border-color:#ccc">
     <input style="display:none" type="submit" name="method" value="repackage">
     <span>Update Config</span>
    </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well. Manipulate the appearance using the bootstrap button classes.

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
 <input class="d-none" type="submit" name="method" value="repackage">
 Update Config
</label>
```