# get clicked button's name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following button with event attached:

```
<button className="pull-right btn btn-success" onClick={this.onNextStep}>Next</button>
```

OnNextStep:

```
onNextStep: function (e) {
    ...
}
```

How do I get the button name inside onNextStep?

e.target.value is not working

And how do I change it?

Comment: `e.innerHTML` should work. A button doesn't have a value.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell Are you sure? MDN (and functioning code) seem to think otherwise, e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701831/438992) *This* button doesn't, but I'm pretty sure they *can*.

Comment: I realize OP is using React, but this question has nothing to do with React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target.textContent` will give you the text of the button

Comment: I don't know why they give you negative rating but this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="pull-right btn btn-success"
  onClick={() => this.onNextStep('Next')}
>
  Next
</button>
```

Remember that React is mostly about writing to the DOM. Rarely do you read from it. (The exception being inputs.)

Your "value" is just a static piece of text. There is no need to get what you've already got.

Answer (score 0):

You need a name attribute on that button `name="next step"` and you'll get it via `e.target.name`. To change it you could assign `name={this.state.buttonName}` and set state on that key when you need to (`this.setState({ buttonName: "new button name" });`). If you are talking about inner HTML as in the comment by Matthew, your button's name could be called from state `<button>{this.state.name}</button>` and setState could change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

in react you can use
onClick{(e) => e.target.innerHTML }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34663207)