# Submit buttons: button text different from value

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am writing a search form in PHP.
I want the user to be able to add search fields using following submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="fields" value="<?php echo $fields+1 ?>" />
```

Now the button shows the value of `$fields + 1`.
Actually what I want is the button to show something else (like *add new field*).
Just adding text between the `<input>...</input>` tags does not help.
The text just appears right of the button.

How do I change the text on the button and still pass the value of `$fields + 1` to GET/POST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Submit-button: Different value / button-text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an hidden input to store the value count, it will be available after GET/POST:

```
<input type="submit" name="fields" value="add new field" />
<input type="hidden" name="fieldsCount" value="<?php echo $fields+1 ?>" />
```

Comment: may not work when you have multiple submit fields, and need different value for each internally (not visible), with different names for each externally (visible)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the button element:

```
<button type="submit" name="seven" value="7">Push Me</button>
```

Refs: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer.  Maybe it's a new feature since that answer?

Answer (score 3):

You Can use the hidden field to store or post the `$fields+1` value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php echo $fields+1 ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Send" />
```