# html changing the submit button value

Tags: php, html, submit

I am working on a simple php html code that get products information from the database, each product has a submit button and its value must be the id of the product like this:

```
<input  type="submit" name="productId" value="' .$row['produc_id'] . '"  />
```

and in the next page I can know the product id that the user choose using this:

```
$productId = $_POST['productId'];
```

the code above will works fine, but the problem is that I can't put any text in the submit buttons, text like buy or add to cart and all the submit buttons has a numbers value which is the id of the products.

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
<input  type="submit"  value=" buy "  />

<input  type="hidden" name="productId" value="' .$row['produc_id'] . '"  />
```

Comment: The core of this question was asked a different way. Take a look at this question, and it's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text

Comment: @Thomas Andrews it gives me the wrong id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably try something like this:

```
<form action="someaction.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" value="12" name="productId">Submit ME</button>
    <button type="submit" value="13" name="productId">Submit Too</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enclosed your inputs within a form-tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form-product" value="PRODUCT_ID" />
    <input type="submit" name="form-submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Then you can use isset() to check whether the form has been submitted, and if so, use the information in the submitted, hidden input field.

```
<?PHP 
    if (isset($_POST['form-submit']))
        echo "Product ID: ".$_POST['form-product']; 
?>
```

---

**FYI**: I noticed that you have typed: `$row['produc_id']`, is it maybe a typo there and it should be: `$row['product_id']`     (missing a t in producT).