# PHP - database query based

Tags: php

I have built a table in PHP to display a list of people and data relating to them. I want the user to be able to select one of those users to send an e-mail request to. So I have put a button at the end of each row for every user.

Im not sure how to write the PHP script to identify which button has been pressed. I have tried assigning the name of the button to be the e-mail address of the user for the row but I dont know how to read that value in the corresponding script...

Code for initial page:

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query))
{

echo "<fieldset>";

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{

    echo "<tr><th>Name</th>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Country'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Profile'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Email'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<input type = "submit" name="$Email" value="connect">';

}
echo "</table>";
echo "</fieldset>";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to do this in HTML5, you could alter the submit button, so that it would redirect to a page, where you can get the e-mail by `$_GET[];`

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" formaction=\"request.php?email=".$Email."\" value="Submit">\";
```

Then in your request.php you could use:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was probably the closest to what I envisaged I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to change name attribute from "$Email" to, I don't know, maybe "user_email" and assign $email variable to value attribute. So in script which must handle this form you will just need to retrieve a value of $_POST['user_email'].

Also I think it's better to use $Email in double quotes:

```
echo "<input name='$Email'" ...>;
```

because you will get string '$Email' instead of expected email address.

Or you can create a form for each table row.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways you could approach this, but I would personally choose to use an HTML form for this purpose.  Consider the following HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="email" value="test1@email.web">test 1</input>
    <button type="submit" name="email" value="test2@email.web">test 2</input>
    <button type="submit" name="email" value="test3@email.web">test 3</input>
</form>
```

If you were to try to click on one of these buttons, you'd notice your query string will now show `?email=test2%40email.web` (assuming you clicked the second button).

The gist of this approach is to use the same `name` attribute for your submit buttons, but assign a different value to each.  I chose `button` over `input` due to the ability to present button text different from the `value` attribute (as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text)).

Applying this principle in your PHP, you'd get something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{

    echo "<tr><th>Name</th>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Country'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Profile'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Email'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<button type="submit" name="email_address" value="' . $Email . '">Send email</button>';

}
```

Then, you just check your `email_address` parameter for the email address.

Comment: Wouldnt the value print on the button by doing that?

Comment: No, that's the beautiful part -- the `button` allows you to treat it as though it were a `input` of type `submit`, while still allowing you to have a `value` attribute that differs from the actual button of the text.