# PHP POST is not sending the value that is needed

Tags: php, post

My form consists of 2 clickable buttons:

```
echo '<input id='99999' type=\'submit\' name=\'send\' class=\'btn btn-default\' value=\'Some Action'/>';
echo '<input id='99988' type=\'submit\' name=\'send\' class=\'btn btn-default\' value=\'Another Action'/>';
```

Therefore the 2 buttons are loaded in my view, visible as `Some Action` and `Another Action.`

Moving over to my controller:

```
echo ($_POST['send']);
```

prints out `Some Action` and `Another Action` when clicked on, accordingly.

Unfortunately, I want the `id` field to get passed to the POST. (Want the controller to print `99999` and `99988`). How can I make this happen?

I also tried `echo <button ... >` in the view but that did not pass the POST at all.

Comment: Only the name and value attributes of the inputs are passed when you post a form.

Comment: You could use 2 forms and put a hidden input in both with the correct name - value pair. And the correct button.

Comment: What can I do to pass the integer to the POST and display the text on the button? I can change the attributes of the button/input accordingly.

Comment: @jeroen I don't need to pass the text, only the integer field. I'm sure there is an easier way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Submit-button: Different value / button-text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text)

Comment: @john It was just an example, the solution you accepted or Ajax are others. It all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<button>` element for this:

```
<button value='99988' name='send' class='btn btn-default'>Another Action</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was missing something simple.