# Change Input value and Placeholder

Tags: html

COUNTER COUNTER EDIT:

**Sorry for obvious question, my edits keep getting deleted but was just saying been working non stop and had a complete blank when trying to remember this, thanks to the Stack community though!**

I have my HTML here:

```
<input type="submit" name="buddy1" value="Yes" placeholder="Toggle Yes">
```

I want the input value to be Yes but the text displayed to be "Toggle Yes". I know there's a trick with span classes and buttons but I want the button to also be the submit. Is there a quick way of doing this WITHOUT Javascript?

Comment: I don't understand you question that well. So you want an input that always displays *Toggle* followed by an input? Why not using a label?

Comment: The placeholder attribute on an input with type submit is invalid

Comment: duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<button></button>` instead:

`<button type="submit" name="buddy1" value="Yes">Toggle Yes</button>`

Comment: Thank you perfect, knew I was being stupid. I am good at this I promise just soo soooo tired I can't think straight. Appreciate the help buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

Your should use a button element, where you can change the text of the button. Buttons elements are just input elements which have more options. From the [w3 site](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) on `button`:

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering possibilities:

For example.
`<button type="submit" name="buddy1" value="Yes">Toggle Yes</button>`